# Google Cloud Platform url resolving

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the billing usage report, links are given in the form of:

```
com.google.cloud/services/big-query/ActiveStorage
```

Does this correspond to an actual url? If so, what would that be?

Comment: Where do you see that i.e. the field? I can't see it in my exports (to BigQuery).

Comment: @GrahamPolley its for billing usage reports for GCP: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export

Comment: That link is GCE specific. I'm not following you :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At close look it looks like a namespace, as it's starts with `com`.

The link you posted actually describes as `MeasurementId`:

> The ID of the type of resource that is being measured. For example,
>   VmimageN1Standard_1 to represent an n1-standard-1 machine type.
>   Example: com.google.cloud/services/compute‑engine/VmimageN1Standard_1

also gives an example that contains `Resource URI`

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| Report Date |                        MeasurementId                         | Quantity |  Unit   |                                            Resource URI                                            | Resource ID |   Location    |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| 02/13/2014  | com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/VmimageN1Standard_1 |    86400 | seconds | https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/instances/my-instance | 16557630484 | us-central1-a |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I think you could actually use `Resource URI` instead of `MeasurementId` to match billing export items.

Comment: What does it have to do with BigQuery though? Maybe I'm missing something..

Comment: He exported the billing usage reports, and one line in that export references BQ, they are using BQ that's the connection. He just used that as example line.

Comment: Right, got it now! Do you think this questions should still be tagged with BigQuery though?

Comment: @Pentium10 how did you connect MesurementID with Resouce URI in my billing export there is no resource URI

Comment: it's there for me, not sure what's going on for you